# CakePHP 2: Controlling recursive on associated models

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

My CakePHP 2 app is running into performance issues due to the amount of data fetched from my associations when pulling from the database. One example of this is in my `Task` element.  A `Task` has many `Files`, `Comments`.  Thus when I pull a `Task` from the database I receive the details about the `Task`, as well as all the details about all the `Files` and `Comments` associated with that `Task`, as well as other associations related to files/comments such as the users who posted them.

Now I know that I can use recursive to control the amount of data fetched when pulling tasks from the database and that:

```
$this->Task->recursive = -1
```

will completely prevent any associations from being fetched.  However I still would like to be able to get very basic data about `Comments` and `Files`, I just want to be able to reduce the associations fetched further down the line. Something like:

```
$this->Task->Comment->recursive = -1
```

Is there a way in CakePHP to get finer control over the recursion of my associated models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a perfect control of recursion level of association, you should use [the containable behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) . This behavior allow you to select only some related records and you can also choose some fields of associated models, to activate containable behavio you can use this code:

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

And to select a related models with some fields you can use this code:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
     'contain' => array(
         'RelatedModel1',
         'RelatedModel2' => array(
            'fields' => array('field1', 'field2'),
         ),
         'RelatedModel3' => array(
            'RelatedModel3RelatedModel'
        )
    )
));
```